# Tensorflow limiting batch size when learning embeddings

Tags: tensorflow, word-embedding

I'm trying to learn the state embeddings for a sequence of states produced by a HMM, similar to how the tensorflow [Vector Representation of Words](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/word2vec/index.html) does this for text sequences.

My issue is that the "vocabulary" of this HMM is only 12 different states. Tensorflow doesn't seem to like it when I run my code using batches larger than the size of this vocabulary. For example, attempting to train it with a batch size of 14 gives the error:

```
F tensorflow/core/kernels/range_sampler.cc:86] Check failed: batch_size + avoided_values.size() <= range_ (14 vs. 12)
Abort trap: 6
```

What is the motivation behind this check?

Answer (score 6):

If you are following the [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.8/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py) from the tutorial

This error actually comes when you set the `num_sampled > len(vocabulary)`

```
num_sampled = 64    # Number of negative examples to sample.
```

you cannot indeed sample indexes (for the negative examples in word to vec) beyond the vocabulary size